# $\nabla u=0$ implies $u$ is constant everywhere or almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega )$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ is open and connected. If $\nabla u=0$ do we have that $u$ is constant every where or a.e. only ?

---

**Added**

Let $\Omega $ an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ s.t $\Omega \subset \{0\leq x_d\leq 1\}$. Prove that there is $C>0$ s.t. for all $u\in \mathcal C_0^1(\Omega )$

$$\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^p\geq \int_\Omega |u|^p.$$

**Proof**

Suppose by contradiction, it doesn't hold. We can assume WLOG that $\Omega $ is connected

**Q1) why such an hypothesis ? Does all open is a finite union of connected set ?**

Then, there is $u_n$ s.t. $$\|\nabla u_n\|_{L^p(\Omega )}\to 0,\quad \|u_n\|_{L^p(\Omega )}=1.$$
By embedding theorem, there is a subsequence (still denoted $(u_n)$) that converge strongly to $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega )$. Therefore, $$\nabla u=0,$$
and thus $u=C$ a.e. in $\Omega $. Since $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega )$, we have that $u=0$ what contradict $\|u\|=1$.

**Q2) Since $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega )$ we can say that $u=0$ on the boundary, but it's measure is nulle. So how can they conclude that $u=0$ a.e. in $\Omega $ ?**

Comment: The elements of Sobolev spaces are not defined pointwise, so we may only have almost-everywhere *something*.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thanks a lot. I added more context, could you tell me why they conclude that $u=0$ a.e. since $u=0$ on the boundary that is of measure nulle ?

Comment: Q1) Not every bounded, open set is a finite union of connected sets, but by adding to $\Omega$ at most countable segments you can make it path-connected, and such segments are neglected by $\int$ since they have measure zero. So you may just assume that $\Omega$ is connected at once.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I'm sorry, I don't really understand. $\Omega $ is a union at most countable of connected set ?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a [second-countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see the property of "union of countable connected composant" in your link.

Comment: That's straightfoward. $\Omega$ is the union of at most countable balls, the balls are connected sets, the connected components of $\Omega$ cannot be more than countable.